# TypeScript. Type error when creating new object with spread operator

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

```
class Todo {
    private _date: Date;
    public name: string;

    constructor(todo: Todo) {
        this._date = todo._date;
        this.name = todo.name;
    }

    get date() { ... }
}
```

```
// example
const todos = Agent.fetchTodos();

const modifiedTodos1 = map.todos(todo => new Todo(todo)); // works fine
const modifiedTodos2 = map.todos(todo => new Todo( { ...todo, _date: new Date() } )); // doesn't work
```

The second `modifiedTodos2` line of code gives me the following error: *property `date` is missing in type [...]*

In my scenario, I'm required to use the spread operator to extend the todo object with an additional prop. But I'm not sure why I'm seeing this error and how to deal with it...
and I also can't make the `date` optional with `?` operator.

Thank you so much in advance for pointing out why my scenario doesn't work and what to do to make it work!

Comment: I think this declaration `get date() { ... }` is restricting the creation of additional properties or at least is setting the attr `date` as a required property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is wrong because you do not consider encapsulation. `_date` is a private field that should not be accessed outside of the object. You defined the getter `date`, use it.

You should not use

`this._date = todo._date;`

but

`this._date = todo.date;`.

Here is an example :

```
class Todo {
  private _date: Date;
  public name: string;

  constructor(todo) {
    this._date = todo.date;
    this.name = todo.name;
  }

  get date(): Date {
    return this._date;
  }
}

const todo = new Todo(null);

const modifiedTodos1 = new Todo(todo);

const modifiedTodos2 = new Todo({
  ...todo,
  date: new Date(),
});
```

---

Also note that it will not work if you strongly type `todo` in the constructor like:

```
  constructor(todo: Todo) {
    this._date = todo.date;
    this.name = todo.name;
  }
```

Because typescript is waiting for a `Todo` object that you do not provide using the spread operator *(no date function)*.

To adress this issue I recommend you to specify an interface that will only contains your setters data.

```
interface ITodo {
  date: Date,
  name: string,
}

class Todo {
  private _date: Date;
  public name: string;

  constructor(todo: ITodo) {
    this._date = todo.date;
    this.name = todo.name;
  }

  get date(): Date {
    return this._date;
  }
}

const todo = new Todo(null);

const modifiedTodos1 = new Todo(todo);

const modifiedTodos2 = new Todo({
  ...todo,
  date: new Date(),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition of previous answer. Except of interface, you can use types:

```
declare type TodoType ={
    name:string,
    date:Date
}
class Todo {
    private _date: Date;
    public name: string;

    constructor(todo: TodoType) {
        this._date = todo.date;
        this.name = todo.name;
    }

    otherBehavior = ()=> {}

    get date() { return this._date;}
}

const toDos:Array<Todo> = [];

const modifiedTodos2 = toDos.map(todo => new Todo( { ...todo, date: new Date() } ));
```

This way you can add additional behavior(properties/methods) to your `Todo` class and there will not be need to pass these in the object which you pass to create instance of `Todo`